# Downscaling a deployment violates the defined affinity rules

Tags: kubernetes

## The scenario

I have a k8s cluster with 3 worker nodes (v1.22.17) and a deployment with 12 replicas. The deployment has a `podAntiAffinity` rule defined with `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` configured as it's shown:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment

  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 12
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app: nginx
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

The pod distribution on the cluster respects the `podAntiAffinity` and it's something like this:

| Node 1 | Node 2 | Node 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nginx-1, nginx-4, nginx-7, nginx-10 | nginx-2, nginx-5, nginx-8, nginx-11 | nginx-3, nginx-6, nginx-9, nginx-12 |

However, when I try to downscale to 6 replicas using <kbd>kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas 6</kbd> the `podAntiAffinity` policy is violated and I get a pod distribution like this:

| Node 1 | Node 2 | Node 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nginx-1, nginx-4, <s>nginx-7</s>, <s>nginx-10</s> | nginx-2, <s>nginx-5</s>, <s>nginx-8</s>, <s>nginx-11</s> | nginx-3, nginx-6, nginx-9, <s>nginx-12</s> |

## The question

How can I have an evently distributed deployment? Each node should have 2 replicas of the deployment. Why is nginx-9 not being terminated and nginx-5 being terminated?

According to [k8s ReplicaSet docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#scaling-a-replicaset), the ReplicaSet controller chooses which pods to delete based on:

1. Pod status
2. `controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost`
3. **Pods on nodes with more replicas come before pods on nodes with fewer replicas.**
4. Pod creation time

## A workaround

I found a workaround. Downscaling gradually the deployment with the following instructions works correctly and leaves a cluster with an evently distributed deployment:

1. <kbd>kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas 11</kbd>
2. <kbd>kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas 10</kbd>
3. <kbd>kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas 9</kbd>
4. <kbd>kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas 8</kbd>
5. <kbd>kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas 7</kbd>
6. <kbd>kubectl scale deployment nginx --replicas 6</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The Scheduler is the component that decides how and where to reallocate the Pods (based on constraints such as taint/toleration, nodeAffinity, etc. and available resources).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/#synopsis

Probably the pattern you shared will change randomly.

> Factors that need to be taken into account for scheduling decisions include individual and collective resource requirements, hardware / software / policy constraints, affinity and anti-affinity specifications, data locality, inter-workload interference, and so on.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/

To have much more control over your Scheduler, I suggest you dedicate Nodes to the indicated application and do some tuning by considering inserting the *percentageOfNodesToScore* value.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/scheduler-perf-tuning/

Comment: The application must be evenly distributed across all the worker nodes to increase fault toleration so dedicating some nodes to this deployment would not fit for me. I've read the docs and maybe I'm missing something, but how can _percentageOfNodesToScore_ help on a small cluster with few nodes? Quoting the Scheduler Performance Tuning docs: _In clusters with less than 50 feasible nodes, the scheduler still checks all the nodes because there are not enough feasible nodes to stop the scheduler's search early._